# Android Descendants focus within a scrollview

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-webview, android-scrollview

I have multiple components within a LinearLayout under a parent ScrollView.

The structure of my layout is something like below:-

```
<ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>
   <ImageView/>
   <WebView/>
   <LinearLayout/>
   <EditText/>
   <Button/>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the parent LinearLayout in order to make sure that the page does not scroll down to the EditText/WebView. But doing this, the EditText/Buttons do not gain focus even on doing the below on the click event of the edittext/button.

```
editText.requestFocus()
```

How do I make sure that the focus remains at the top of the page and the edittext and button get focus on clicking it?